# why does modulus by a large number seem to give a wrong answer in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to find trailing numbers of zeros in a number, here is my code:

```
public class TrailingZeroes {
    public static void  bruteForce(int num){ //25
        double fact = num; //25
        int numOfZeroes = 0;

        for(int i= num - 1; i > 1; i--){
            fact = fact * (i);
        }
        System.out.printf("Fact: %.0f\n",fact); //15511210043330984000000000

        while(fact % 10 == 0){
          fact = fact / 10;
          double factRem = fact % 10;
          System.out.printf("Fact/10: %.0f\n",fact); //1551121004333098400000000
            System.out.printf("FactRem: %.0f\n",factRem); // 2?
          numOfZeroes++;
        }

        System.out.println("Nnumber of zeroes "+ numOfZeroes); //1

    }
}
```

As you can see the fact%10

Comment: That's because it is not in the range of an `int`. Use `BigInteger` or `long`

Comment: Look up "int overflow"

Comment: isn't it double tho i mean fact%10 and thus shouldn't it be in range

Comment: Ah double, I did not see that, then this: `while(fact % 10 == 0){` is almost guaranteed to fail since digital computers cannot represent double to that degree of precision.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### You use *floating point* data type illegally.

The `float` and `double` primitive types in Java are [floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) numbers, where the number is stored as a binary representation of a fraction and a exponent.

More specifically, a [double-precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) floating point value such as the `double` type is a 64-bit value, where:

- 1 bit denotes the sign (positive or negative).
- 11 bits for the exponent.
- 52 bits for the significant digits (the fractional part as a binary).

These parts are combined to produce a `double` representation of a value.

For a detailed description of how floating point values are handled in Java, see the [Section 4.2.3: Floating-Point Types, Formats, and Values](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.3) of the Java Language Specification.

The `byte`, `char`, `int`, `long` types are [fixed-point][6] numbers, which are exact representions of numbers. Unlike fixed point numbers, floating point numbers will some times (safe to assume "most of the time") not be able to return an exact representation of a number. This is the reason why you end up with `11.399999999999` as the result of `5.6 + 5.8`.

When requiring a value that is exact, such as 1.5 or 150.1005, you'll want to use one of the fixed-point types, which will be able to represent the number exactly.

As has been mentioned several times already, Java has a [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) class which will handle very large numbers and very small numbers.

---

```
public static void bruteForce(int num) {    //25
    double fact = num;

    // precision was lost on high i
    for (int i = num - 1; i > 1; i--)
        fact *= i;

    String str = String.format("%.0f", fact);   //15511210043330984000000000
    System.out.println(str);

    int i = str.length() - 1;
    int numOfZeroes = 0;

    while (str.charAt(i--) == '0')
        numOfZeroes++;

    System.out.println("Number of zeroes " + numOfZeroes);  //9
}
```